# Multiple value parameter ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm having a mental block here.
What I'm trying to do is allow the user to select 1 or multiple values for the parameter.

So here is my parameter allowed values @Group

```
SELECT GROUPID,GroupName FROM dbo.tbl_Group WHERE GroupId In (1,7,11,12,14,15)
```

Users should be able to pick one or multiple values ie 1 or 1 and 7 so on.

My query is set to pick up the value of the parameter with this.

```
AllocatedGroup IN (@Group)
```

My problem is i can select multiple values and it works perfectly however if they select just 1 value it doesn't bring back any data

I can fix this by changing the query to say `AllocatedGroup = (@Group)`
But that would remove the ability to select multiple values.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR and combine = and IN to match both cases.

```
WHERE GroupId IN (@group) OR GroupId = @group
```